# Can't set AWS ECS service auto scaling in Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

I am experimenting with the AWS CLI for application-autoscaling, and wanted to view how making changes in the CLI were reflected in the AWS console.

I set register-scalable-target with new a new minimum and maximum. When I updated the same service in the AWS Console, why is there no option to set autoscaling minimum and maximum values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer! The autoscaling page is not (yet?) available in the "New ECS Experience." If you switch to the "classic" experience by flipping the toggle in the upper-left corner to the off position, then edit the service, you will see the autoscaling page.

(The page will also show the values set with the AWS CLI 'application-autoscaling register-scalable-target' command.)

Comment: It is weird that is says you posted both the question and answer at `2022-04-24 14:36:36Z`. It is of course fine to answer your own question, but I don't understand how you posted them both at the same second.

Comment: It gives you an option to answer your own question when you create it, and I thought others might run into the same thing…